# Get a specific part from a string based on a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in this format:

```
ABCD_EFDG20120700.0.xml
```

This has a pattern which has three parts to it:

1. First is the set of chars before the '`_`', the '`ABCD`'
2. Second are the set of chars '`EFDG`' after the '`_`'
3. Third are the remaining `20120700.0.xml`

I can split the original string and get the number(s) from the second element in the split result using this switch:

```
\d+
```

```
Match m = Regex.Match(splitname[1], "\\d+");
```

That returns only '`20120700`'. But I need '`20120700.0`'.

How do I get the required string?

Comment: string input = "ABCD_EFDG20120700.0.xml";

            string pattern = "(?'beginning'[^_]+)_(?'middle'[^\\d]+)(?'end'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string beginning = match.Groups["beginning"].Value;
            string middle = match.Groups["middle"].Value;
            string end = match.Groups["end"].Value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your regex to look for any number of digits, then period and then any number of digits once again:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(splitname[1], "\\d+\\.\\d+");
```

Although with such regular expression you don't even need to split the string:

```
string s = "ABCD_EFDG20120700.0.xml";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, "\\d+\\.\\d+");
string result = m.Value;     // result is 20120700.0
```

Comment: It actually is much more convenient to use verbatim string literals when declaring a regex: `Regex.Match(s, @"\d+\.\d+");`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use one regex operation for all you want like this:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"^([^_]+)_([^\d.]+)([\d.]+\d+)\.(.*)$");
var matches = rgx.Matches(input);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", matches[0].Groups[0]);  // All input string
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", matches[0].Groups[1]);  // ABCD
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", matches[0].Groups[2]);  // EFGH
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", matches[0].Groups[3]);  // 20120700.0
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", matches[0].Groups[4]);  // xml
}
```